# Logistic Regression and Design of experiment

Tags: logistic, experiment-design

I have seven factor and one response variable with 32 run and one replication i.e. 64 runs and I want to use logistics regression. I found in th analysis that 4 out 7 factors are significant. I want to check curvature. If curvature is not significant then should i make some other lay out of DoE only considering only significant factor? and If curvature is significant then should I make other layout with considering all factors?